# Tags and synonyms for background problems, especially for 1D signals

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There is a tag for [background-subtraction](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/background-subtraction), with only 20 questions. Although this term is common in image processing, several questions have been asked recently for signals or time series.

I would like to suggest the creation of a specific tag, with synonyms as many terms are used: [baseline](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baseline) (potentially misleading), [trend](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trend),  [drift](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drift),  [wander](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wander).

- Do you feel (as I do) this is necessary?
- What could be the most appropriate main tag name?

Comment: I do apologize for my lack of knowledge in my ability to create tags, and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose the tag [trend](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trend), which seems the most generic to me, also used in statistics.